# What does "by ginger" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I've come across it in the 15th episode of the 8th season *the Walking Dead*. Here is the context:

> Eugene: If Negan needs bullets to end this war,
>
> then, **by ginger**, he's gonna get 'em.
>
> All of 'em.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [an article](https://www.glossophilia.org/2014/07/jolly-hockey-sticks-and-other-jolly-posh-stuff/) I found online:

> **By George! By golly! By ginger! By gosh!**: Basically a posh old version of OMG! The mild oath or exclamation dates from the early 1600s, when “George” and the other g-words were used as substitutes for God to avoid blasphemy.

So this is a way of saying, "If God wills it," without violating the commandment against "taking God's name in vain."

This phrase sounds distinctly old-fashioned, almost to an absurd degree, to modern ears.

Comment: It sounds closer to "by God!" to me, than to "If God wills it". There's nothing about the latter phrase that needs softening.

Comment: It seems more likely that "By ginger! came from "By Jesus!", like the Irish "Bejasus!" "By George!" may be a shortened form of "By (God and St.) George!" If the G is hard - as in "God" - then "golly" and "gosh" seem appropriate. If soft - as in "Jesus" - then  Jupiter, ginger, Jimminy etc.